# Exec return false even if it work

Tags: php, exec

I want to backup a database so i'm using mysqldump through php to achieve this,in the following way:

```
exec("mysqldump -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p'$dbpass' $d > $bkp_file", $output, $return);
```

I specified the output and return parameters to get a status of the command for the further verification.
The command works,i get the sql file,populated, but the return variable have the value of 0.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

An exit status of zero means success.

Any other value is used to indicate some kind of error. Check the documentation of the launched app for details.

Comment: but why $output is empty? shouldn't it return the cmd line if it succeed?

Comment: You have redirected the output.

Comment: i don't understand , can you explain it please?

Comment: google what? I have no idea what to search for in the first place and i already looked for similar problems,but they also couldn't fix it.I 've read http://php.net/manual/ro/function.exec.php , and couldn't find a solution .